# Linear Transformation using Kernel and Range

Tags: linear-transformations

Suppose that V is finite-dimensional and that the dimension of V is odd. Show that there does NOT exist a linear transformation T : V → V such that
ker(T) = range(T).

I'm just getting thrown off with the fact that the dimension of V is odd. I believe that I have to use the formula that 
dimV = dim ker(T) + dim range(T) but I'm not really sure how to start...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If two numbers are equal they will have the same parity. Is this possible if the sum is odd?

Answer (score 2):

By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim V = \dim \ker T + \dim\operatorname{range}T$. If you know that the dimension of $V$ is odd, what can you deduce about the values of the summands $\dim \ker T$ and $\dim\operatorname{range}T$, and hence the existence of such a linear transformation?

Comment: So since dimV is odd, we can assume that dim Ker T is not equal to dim Range T. Is that enough to imply that there does not exist such a linear map?

Comment: @MichelleDrolet Effectively yes. It might help to assume such a map did exist and then see what that implies about the dimension of $V$. It seems like you're getting the idea.

Comment: Yep! I definitely understand it now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$\dim \ker T$ and $\dim $ range $T$ are two integers whose sum is odd.  So, they can't be equal.  If two spaces have different dimensions, they can't be the same space.